# Want to convert to_char oracle function into the cast statement so that it became ANSI standard

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Below is the oracle query in which i want to replace TO_CHAR with the CAST function.

```
 SELECT   tag.action_log_id,
             TO_CHAR (tag.action_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') action_date,
             tag.tree_node AS chain, tag.environment AS environment,
             tag.table_name AS tablename, tag.action, tag.action_log_sql,
             tag.action_log_xml, tag.user_id
        FROM ods.ods_fooditems_log tag
       WHERE tag.action_date >= TO_DATE ('8/27/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         AND TRUNC (tag.action_date) <= TO_DATE ('8/27/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         AND tag.businessid = 167
    ORDER BY tag.action_log_id DESC
```

Comment: If this is Oracle, please remove the "mysql" tag.  Then, why do you want to do this?  `TO_CHAR()` is a very reasonable function.

Comment: Cast it to what?  Please be specific.

Comment: want to use CAST() function in the query in place of TO_CHAR()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `cast` function instead of the `to_char` function, you can't specify the date format:

```
SQL> select cast(sysdate as Varchar2(15)) strdate from dual;

STRDATE
---------------
27.08.14
```

You have to specify this format on the either session or system or database level:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM";

Session altered.

SQL> select cast(sysdate as Varchar2(25)) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASVARCHAR2(25
-------------------------
08/27/2014 04:22:59 PM
```

Also you can collect this date by chunks:

```
select extract(MONTH from sysdate) || '/' || 
       extract(DAY from sysdate) || '/' || 
       extract(YEAR from sysdate) || ' ' || ' ' ||
       lpad(mod(extract(HOUR from cast(sysdate as timestamp)), 12), 2, '0') || ':' || 
       lpad(extract(MINUTE from cast(sysdate as timestamp)), 2, '0') || ':' || 
       lpad(extract(SECOND from cast(sysdate as timestamp)), 2, '0') || ' ' || 
       case 
         when extract(HOUR from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) / 12 > 1 then 'PM'
         ELSE 'AM'
       end d
     , sysdate current_date
  from dual

        D               CURRENT_DATE
------------------------------------
8/27/2014 02:00:06 PM   08/27/2014
```

Comment: i want my query to compatible in ANSI SQL standard . So is there any other-way around may be without CAST which function i can use to replace TO_CHAR() and provide the desired format.

Comment: Thanks a lot zaratustra for your response. In this change i am still getting the message that Try to convert to ANSI-92.

Comment: I don't understand you [here](https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_169) you can find that the `extract` function is part of the ANSI-92. If you have problems with `lpad` function, you can use the `case` operator, just like I used it for finding out if it is PM or AM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to replace `to_char` with `cast` because they do two different jobs.

The `cast` function changes the *type* of data. Changing the type of the data has no control over the format or the appearance of the data because it has its own internal storage format.

The `to_char` function generates a *string*. In the process you also supply a formatting string to control what the resulting string looks like.

The only time the two functions overlap is if you cast a date to a string. However, you will only get the default date format, so it’s probably a pointless exercise.

As far as I am aware `to_char` is also ANSI compliant, so you may as well stick to it.